# PHP Modulo Decimal

Tags: php, decimal, modulo

How can i do modulo arithmetic with decimal value since PHP only can do modulo with integer?

Example case:

```
 echo 1.92 % 1000; // (int) 1, expected result should be 1.92
```

is there any library to do this correctly?

More info about this modulo arithmetic problem: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34399

Comment: It's not a bug, please look up what modulus is in arithmetic.

Comment: @N.B. I didn't say this is a bug. I aware of PHP Capability about this. what i looking for is solution because this PHP Limitless.

Comment: Why there is people want to close this question? i believe there is much people will also looking solution for this? @_@

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is also a floating point [fmod()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) function

```
echo fmod(1.92, 1000)
```

Comment: @GusDeCooL You should accept an answer if it was helpful and solved Your problem.

Comment: @shadyyx Yes i want to accept it, but following stackoverflow policy i need to wait 6 minutes. LOL.

Comment: Down voted by mistake sorry that's my bad wanted to up vote =D

Answer (score 6):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php

I think you wanted this one, this returns float result?